# What did John McCarthy mean by *pornographic programming*?

Tags: lisp, terminology, history

In the *[History of Lisp](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/history/lisp/node3.html)*, McCarthy writes:

> The unexpected appearance of an interpreter tended to freeze the form of the language, and some of the decisions made rather lightheartedly for the ``Recursive functions ...'' paper later proved unfortunate. These included the COND notation for conditional expressions which leads to an unnecessary depth of parentheses, and the use of the number zero to denote the empty list NIL and the truth value false. Besides encouraging pornographic programming, giving a special interpretation to the address 0 has caused difficulties in all subsequent implementations.

What's he talking about?

Comment: This question was linked [in meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329034)

Comment: it exposes what must be hidden -- exposes implementational details instead of putting up an abstraction level above it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The fact that too many implementation details were leaking at a higher level, i.e. showing up too much

Comment: Would *pornographic programming* then be any code that reaches out of its proper semantic level, like inline assembly?

Comment: That seems to make sense: Code that uses *intimate knowledge*.

Comment: But, strangely, that isn't the case. `NIL` is an abstrated symbol in all the Lisp dialects that descended from MacCarthy's. Programs cannot tell whether it is implemented as the zero address.

Answer (score 24):

> ... zero to denote the empty list ...

because `0==()` has been the emoticon for pornography since 1958.

Now you know.

Comment: Citation needed.

Answer (score 9):

The original Fortran III specification document, a technical paper disseminated in the Winter of 1958, describes some very explicit additions to the Fortran II language, including ... inline assembly.

The PDF document is [here](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Fortran/102679275.05.01.acc.pdf).

A tantalizing description of the "additions" follows:

[image: Extract from I.,Ziller, Additions to Fortran II, 1958]

Some taboo code is

[image: Pornographic programming using the un-released Fortran III]

Mysteriously, Fortran-III was [never released to the public (see section 5.)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.869&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but it was disseminated in a limited fashion before quietly fading away.

Comment: What a fascinating read. I'm more familiar with the work on early languages based on lambda calculus and this is the exact opposite - so mired in machine specific details like registers. How and where did you find this?

Comment: followed a trail of googles to computer history archive. was delighted by it, too. it's great to see the (different from today) perspective that those computer scientists brought to their work... to imagine the future... as they saw it. :)

Comment: How on Earth does this relate to the question? It's not even about the same programming language!

Answer (score 8):

I think it is about mixing numerical and logic values, which can still be seen in popular constructs, probably originated in Fortran, like `while (1)`. There are a lot of "clever" C algorithms, that rely on the fact, that 0 is false and every other value isn't.

The same applies at large to API calls, like in POSIX or Linux kernel, some of which return 0 on failure, while some -1 (there's a rule of thumb, when to apply which, but it is just folklore, so often it is broken). Considering the fact, that at McCarthy's time, those things weren't developed yet, you can see his "prophetic" power even here.

Comment: But traditional Lisps do not do that. Zero isn't false, only NIL is.  Interestingly, Richard Stallman made some Lisp dialect in which zero was false.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it was his way of talking about [null references: the billion dollar mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare) (T. Hoare).

Comment: That could be part of it, but I'd expect there to be an example closer to 1958 (the time discussed in that part of the paper).

Comment: It seems unlikely because as far as I can tell LISP 1 didn't have null references. If you encountered `nil` you encountred not the absence of a reference but an empty list.